# SQL if cell value equals value A or value B

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a proc which has the following select statement in it

```
SELECT expectedValue
FROM dbo.ExclusionValues ev
JOIN dbo.StagingData sd ON ev.ExpectedVale = sd.ProductMainType
                            AND ev.Exclusion1 = sd.CollateralType
                            AND ev Exclusion2 = sd.CollateralType
```

My issue is with `Exclusion1` & `Exclusion2`as I need my select statement to see if `sd.CollateralType` is either `Exclusion1` or `Exclusion2` where as right now, I'm checking on both.

What is the correct syntax for doing so?

The above snippet is from a larger proc I'm adding to and I can't provide more background on it. My issue is having a way to see if `sd.CollateralType` equals either `Exclusion1` or `Exclusion2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `IN` clause

```
SELECT expectedValue
FROM dbo.ExclusionValues ev
JOIN dbo.StagingData sd ON ev.ExpectedVale = sd.ProductMainType
                            AND sd.CollateralType in (ev.Exclusion1, ev.Exclusion2)
```